# Различие в работе эмуляторов iPad и Android

Tags: эмулятор, ipad, android, objective-c, производительность

Почему приложение (Objective-C) при запуске на эмуляторе для iPad работает **быстрее**, чем на самом устройстве, а на эмуляторе для Android (Java приложение) работает **медленнее**, чем на устройстве?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что в случае с iPad это не эмулятор, а симулятор. Эмулятор Android эмулирует ARM на x86, iPad же работает сразу на x86 (поэтому, например, нельзя в симуляторе iPad запустить приложение собранное для устройства).
Соответственно, у любого современного компьютера ресурсов больше, чем у iPhone/iPad, поэтому приложение в симуляторе работает быстрее, чем на устройстве. Эмулятору же Android'а  недостаточно ресурсов компьютера (я ещё не видел компьютера, на котором эмулятор не тормозил бы), он и без всяких приложений заметно медленнее телефонов/планшетов.

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендую прочитать статью на хабре о порте android x86: [Как ускорить эмулятор Android на 400%](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/130201/)

Answer (score 1):

У андроида именно эмулятор т.е. имитация работы процессора  мобильного устройства на х86 компа, все действия при работе выполняются с дополнительным переводом инструкций одного проца под другой, а у iPhone это всего лишь симмуляция - библиотеки и какая-то урезанная версия оси откомпилированы под х86_64 и работают в нативном коде